# Python Pygame Crashing When Opened Code Included

Tags: python

So this is my first question but i kinda got lost with my code so i was wondering if anyone could tell me why its crashing. I'm fairly new to python(though i code other a lot in other languages). So my pygame is basically a cat and mouse game with white being the cat and black the mouse... you get it. Only problem is when i open it i see the blit text for about a second and then it crashes i tried looking over the code a lot but to no avail so it would be very appreciated if someone would look it over for me. (i probably missed something stupid like a incorrect indent).

```
import pygame
import random
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
Green= (0,225,0)

pygame.init()
windowSurface=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
pygame.display.set_caption("1st PyGame")
clock = pygame.time.Clock();
counter, text = 60, '60'.rjust(3)
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 30)


exit = False
xcord=250
ycord=250
xchange=0
ychange=0
xCord=750
yCord=750
xChange=0
yChange=0
while not exit:
    windowSurface.fill((255,0,0))
    text='Cat And Mouse !!!White=Cat(arrow-keys) Black=Mouse(wasd)!!! White Wins By Catching Black But If Black Lasts A Minute Then Black Wins!!!'
    windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 500))
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(15)
    text='Get Ready Game Starts In 15 Seconds'
    windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 500))
    clock.tick(60)
    time.sleep(15)
    start_ticks=pygame.time.get_ticks()
    seconds=(pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks)/1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            exit=True
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                xChange-=10
                yChange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xChange+=10
                yChange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                xChange+=0
                yChange-=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                xChange+=0
                yChange+=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                xchange-=10
                ychange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                xchange+=10
                ychange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                xchange+=0
                ychange-=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_s:
                xchange+=0
                ychange+=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_s:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
    crashxCord1=xCord+10
    crashxCord2=xCord-10
    crashyCord1=yCord+10
    crashyCord2=yCord-10


    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==pygame.USEREVENT: 
            counter-=1
            text=str(counter).rjust(3) if counter > 0 else 'Black Wins'
        if e.type==pygame.QUIT: break
    else:
        if text=='Black Wins':
            windowSurface.fill(0,0,0)
            screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
            time.sleep(10)
            exit=True
        else:
            screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)


    if crashxCord1<=xcord and crashxCord2>=xcord and crashyCord1<=ycord and crashyCord2>=ycord:
        text='White Wins'
        windowSurface.fill(255,255,255)
        screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        time.sleep(10)
        exit=True
    pygame.display.update()
    xcord+=xchange
    ycord+=ychange
    xCord+=xChange
    yCord+=yChange
    windowSurface.fill(red)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, black, ([xcord,ycord,20,20]))
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, ([xCord,yCord,20,20]))
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a very small, but fatal mistake. You forgot to import the time module!

```
import time
```

Put this line directly after `import pygame`, and that will solve your first problem.

The next issue is that you are causing a time.sleep in each frame. when you have a pygame window open, you NEVER want a time.sleep call. If in this time the user makes any interaction with the window, the program will become unresponsive, and crash. I created a small function and replaced it with the delays so the user can interact with the screen while paused.

This is one of the many little things that will cause a new pygame developer to tear all of your hair out!

I would recommend giving this book a read:
http://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781590598726

It explains all of the Pygame conventions and standards. This is the book I used to get started with Pygame development

Your collision detection is hard to hit. The cat must be exactly on top of the mouse to win. If this is what you want, here is your working code. If you want just touching, say the word, and I will show you how to do this.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
Green= (0,225,0)

pygame.init()
windowSurface=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
pygame.display.set_caption("1st PyGame")
clock = pygame.time.Clock();
counter, text = 60, '60'.rjust(3)
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 30)


exit = False
xcord=250
ycord=250
xchange=0
ychange=0
xCord=750
yCord=750
xChange=0
yChange=0

def create_delay(delay):
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < delay:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

windowSurface.fill((255,0,0))
text='Cat And Mouse !!!White=Cat(arrow-keys) Black=Mouse(wasd)!!! White Wins By Catching Black But If Black Lasts A Minute Then Black Wins!!!'
windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 500))
pygame.display.flip()
create_delay(1)
text='Get Ready Game Starts In 15 Seconds'
windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 500))
clock.tick(60)
create_delay(1)

while not exit:

    start_ticks=pygame.time.get_ticks()
    seconds=(pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks)/1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            exit=True
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                xChange-=10
                yChange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xChange+=10
                yChange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                xChange+=0
                yChange-=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                xChange+=0
                yChange+=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                xChange=0
                yChange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                xchange-=10
                ychange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                xchange+=10
                ychange+=0
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                xchange+=0
                ychange-=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_s:
                xchange+=0
                ychange+=10
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_s:
                xchange=0
                ychange=0
    crashxCord1=xCord+10
    crashxCord2=xCord-10
    crashyCord1=yCord+10
    crashyCord2=yCord-10

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==pygame.USEREVENT: 
            counter-=1
            text=str(counter).rjust(3) if counter > 0 else 'Black Wins'
        if e.type==pygame.QUIT: break
    else:
        if text=='Black Wins':
            windowSurface.fill(0,0,0)
            windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
            time.sleep(10)
            exit=True
        else:
            windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)

    if crashxCord1<=xcord and crashxCord2>=xcord and crashyCord1<=ycord and crashyCord2>=ycord:
        text='White Wins'
        windowSurface.fill(255,255,255)
        windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        time.sleep(10)
        exit=True

    pygame.display.update()
    xcord+=xchange
    ycord+=ychange
    xCord+=xChange
    yCord+=yChange
    windowSurface.fill(red)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, black, ([xcord,ycord,20,20]))
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, ([xCord,yCord,20,20]))
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Good first try though!
Hope this helps, and good luck with Pygame!

[EDIT]

To make the user win when the 2 rectangles touch, I used the collidepoint function for each of the corners of the mouse. This function detects if a specified point is inside a rectangle object.

This part goes right after you move each rectangle:

```
windowSurface.fill(red)
cat = pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, black, ([xcord,ycord,20,20]))
mouse = pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, ([xCord,yCord,20,20]))

if cat.collidepoint(xCord, yCord) or cat.collidepoint(xCord + 20, yCord) or cat.collidepoint(xCord, yCord + 20) or cat.collidepoint(xCord+20, yCord+20):
    text='White Wins'
    windowSurface.fill((255,255,255))
    windowSurface.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    create_delay(10)
    exit=True
    continue

clock.tick(60)
```

If you need additional help, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: yeah i would like so if its just touching at all. and thanks for the delay function. im also gonna check out the book!!!